# Can tmux save commands to a file, like .bash_history?

Tags: linux, history, tmux

Does tmux support saving to a file the commands typed in "C-b :" mode ? I'd rather look through the ones I already typed than have to look each command up in the man page.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is `history-file` option which does what you are looking for.

> **history-file** path
>
> If not empty, a file to which tmux will write command prompt history on exit and load it from on start.

Add this to your `.tmux.conf`

```
set -g history-file ~/.tmux_history
```

**Note** it was added in 2.1 version. if you have older version of tmux read
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26548/write-all-tmux-scrollback-to-a-file