# tmux: list command-prompt history?

Tags: linux, terminal, command, history, tmux

I know you can scroll line by line through the tmux command-prompt history (C-b :, then arrow through them).

I'm looking for a way to see a list of the last N-number of commands from that history, but I'm not finding a way to do this.

Is it possible?

Comment: Voting to close this question as off-topic. Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. The help also has suggestions for other SE sites where this question may be appropriate.

Comment: Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think there is a way to do this without setting `history-file` setting([Can tmux save commands to a file, like .bash_history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39368285/can-tmux-save-commands-to-a-file-like-bash-history/39383198#39383198))

In `.tmux.conf` add the line

```
set -g history-file ~/.tmux_history
```

After that is set, you can use standard file reading programs to get the `N`th line. For example:

```
tail -n N ~/.tmux_history | head -n 1
```

where `N` is number of your line.

Comment: It works only if I put `-s` option : `set -sg history-file ~/.tmux_history`

Comment: Where does it store the history when it's not set?

Comment: @NikhilCSB From docs

`history-file path
             If not empty, a file to which tmux will write command prompt history on exit and load it from on start.`

So history is available while your server is active, and after you close it history is dropped. Or you could have `history-file` set somewhere you can check it with `tmux show-option -g history-file`